# Multiple date formats in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime, date-formatting

When formatting datetimes, datestrings and datenums in MATLAB there are two different ways in which minutes and months are represented, either as M and m or m and M respectively. Concretely, when you use when you use datestr it is different to when you use datetime. Here is an example,

```
startdate='01/05/2015 12:35:22';
startdt=datetime(startdate,'InputFormat','dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
startstr=datestr(startdt,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');
```

See how for datestr we use lower-case m for month and for datetime we use upper-case M for month.

Why does MATLAB have different date formats that are applicable for these commands? What's the best approach in order to implement a consistent style of date formats in my code?

Comment: Possibly  ISO 8601 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime

Comment: Well, yes it is a complaint but my question was "why do they change for m for month in one area to M for month in another?". I keep writing code for datestr then get in the groove and write the same format for datetime and it breaks my code. I guess if I understand the reason why it will stop me from doing this.

Comment: @doctorlove This does not really support using lower case year anywhere. I guess that the reason may be obscure if there are one. However, this does rather seem to be a complaint than a programming question so I will flag this as unclear what you ask.

Comment: I have now edited my question and the example to make clearer what I am asking. Sam Roberts understood exactly what I was asking so I am not sure why this is on hold. Feedback gratefully received.

Comment: I suspect the question was closed/put on hold because it was formulated as something close to a complaint/rant about MATLAB, rather than as the direct question that I'm sure you intended. I've edited it to reflect that, and voted to reopen. The direct question seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In R2014b MathWorks introduced a new suite of functionality (based around the `datetime` class) to handle dates and times, that is intended to be used as a much improved replacement for older functions such as `datestr`, `datenum` and `datevec`.

One of the issues with the older functionality was that it did not use standard format strings to describe date and time formats. The newer functionality does it correctly, conforming to ISO 8601. It also has proper support for timezones and locales, calendar-based durations, and nanosecond precision.

The older functions have nevertheless been kept, for backward-compatibility. It's possible that in some future version of MATLAB they may start to be phased out gradually. The usual process for that would be that for a couple of versions they would raise a (suppressible) warning, indicating that you might like to modify your code to use the newer functionality; and then a few versions later they would be removed (which would finally cause code still using them to error).

I would suggest that if you're writing new code, you exclusively stick to using functionality based around `datetime`. If you're modifying existing code, try to be consistent in your choices, but gradually migrate your code to the newer functionality when appropriate.

Comment: Brilliant. This is the exact kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general issue by Mathworks, and something many MATLAB programmers complain about:

> Mathworks keeps changing general things from one release to another

This is in particular very cumbersome, when e.g. you suddenly have to deal with case-sensitive (happened from 2007 to 2008 I think?), or when you suddenly have new def-colors in you plots, very different OOP handling (the first OOP was a nightmare) etc.

To you question: both functions you mention are basically doing the same thing but were introduced in very different releases.

- datestr before 2006
- datetime after 2014

So I quess the comment of doctorlove is correct, Mathworks changed this formatting to be more similar to ISO-norms. Even on the mathworks website you can find a very slight comment

> Note:   The letter identifiers that datetime accepts are different from those used by the datestr, datenum, and datevec functions.